# How can I use Counter Strike 1.6 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, wine, games

I wish to install Counter Strike 1.6 on Ubuntu 12.04 under wine, but I don't know where to get the source (I have an exe setup file) or how to run it under wine. I will connect to international servers using IP.

Please, give me step by step instructions on where to download the source and how to run it under wine. I'm fairly new to Linux.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: is CS source also ok?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. I don't have the source. I don't know where to get it.

Comment: I mean there is Counter Strike 1.6 and there is Counter Strike Source. The latter is a newer version. Though it is not the latest version, it is widely used.

Comment: No, I want to run counter-strike 1.6...

Comment: try this tutorial from thinkdigit website http://www.thinkdigit.com/forum/tutorials/98268-howto-counter-strike-1-6-wine.html

Answer (score 6):

Steam Client for Linux was recently officially released for Ubuntu together with the original Half-Life family that includes Counter-Strike 1.6. There is no need to use Wine.

To install Steam, open **Ubuntu Software Center** and search for "steam".

Answer (score 0):

Here's [the missing dll](http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?msvbvm60).

Download it as per your system, then extract it and copy paste it into the CounterSrike installed folder location.

Comment: Is this really the dll? The site looks sort-of like a malware haven.... And what folder does it go in if is the right dll?

Comment: It may appear to be suspected as A MALWARE WEBSITE, but it did not harm in any sort. (.wine/Programfiles/Counterstrike) would be the folder to paste the downloaded dll or the folder where you have installed the Application (CS) .